# Doing an inline if in the action of a form

Tags: php

I need to redirect the user to a site that gets the "Short_proj_name" information. So i did this:

```
<form action="Main.php?short_proj_name=<?=$_REQUEST['short_proj_name']?>" method="post" name="formProjName" target="_blank" id='frmProjName'>
```

However, upon searching, i found out that there are several reasons NOT to use $_REQUEST, one of them being security and all that. However, simply doing $_POST['short_proj_name'] or $_GET['short_proj_name'] never returns the information i need.

Basically, how would i go about doing an if statement that checks if the $_GET is empty, and does a $_POST instead? Can i do that in the action method of my form?

EDIT:
Adittionally, is it possible that maybe using both $_POST and $_GET return null, yet using $_REQUEST doesnt? As far as i know, $_REQUEST is both  get and post together, but none of them returns any information

It works if i do it as so:

```
                if(!empty($_POST['short_proj_name']))
            {
                $projName = $_POST['short_proj_name'];
            }
            elseif (!empty($_GET['short_proj_name']))
            {
                $projName = $_GET['short_proj_name'];
            }
            else
            {
                $projName = $_REQUEST['short_proj_name'];
            }
```

But i'm not sure if that solves the security problem at all

Comment: yes you can do it

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer here is to always use _GET.
A form can actually send both _GET and _POST data based on what you use in the "action" attribute of the form. The action part doesn't care what you set the "method" attribute as.

From what you are showing above, the params are all in the "action" part of the form so these are always passed into _GET anyway. If the inputs were inside the form then those would be received via _POST

Here's an example.
In PHP I would receive $_GET['monkey'] = '1' and $_POST['lion'] = 1

```
<form method='post' action='receive.php?monkey=1'>
<input type='text' name='lion' value='1' />
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

There shouldn't really ever be an instance where you need to check if the answer is in _GET or _POST and as mentioned in a comment, it's quite a security risk to use $_REQUEST or check if it's in _GET or _POST.

Most times, you can just push the page request URL back into the form "action" to ensure all the same _GET params are included on the form _POST.

The big mistake most people do is try to move them from _GET into hidden input fields inside a form thinking they need to do that to carry all that data through.

However, this type of function call might help you but I wouldn't approve of it.

```
function getRequestParam($param){
   if(isset($_GET[$param])){return $_GET[$param];}
   if(isset($_POST[$param])){return $_POST[$param];}
   return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can like

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $projName = $_POST['short_proj_name'];
}
else
{
    $projName = $_GET['short_proj_name'];
}

?>
<form action="Main.php?short_proj_name=<?=$projName ?>" method="post" name="formProjName" target="_blank" id='frmProjName'>
```

but i think it's ugly

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with this code, yet, it returns empty.. hmmm very intriguing. I might need to edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code :

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET) && $_GET['short_proj_name'] != '')
        echo $_GET['short_proj_name'];
    else if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['short_proj_name'] != '')
        echo $_GET['short_proj_name'];
    else
        echo $_REQUEST['short_proj_name'];
?>
```

But if you get the value from a post or get, it can be anything so be careful...
If the "short_proj_name" is a file name, a nasty person can get access to other files just by guessing their names...

Comment: So,  bad advice then?

Comment: of course :) but if it can help for a home work it's ok :)

Comment: No, it's not ok, it's a security issue, plain and simple. This isn't helpful. You agreed "of course" that it's bad advice

Comment: shall i delete the answer ?

Comment: Keep it here, just for reference. It might help me out a bit

Comment: it's a good thing to keep around, as an example of what not to do, and why